# Single Table Inheritance in a rails model after namespace changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have single table inheritance working on one of my models

```
module Mod
  class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  class Ferrari < Car
  end
end
```

and it all works really well;

```
Mod::Car.all
==> select * from cars
Mod::Ferrari.all
==> select * from cars where type = "Ferrari"
```

Not a problem. The requirement (because of DRB) is that we publish these models un-namespaced, so I created a global classes that inherit from the working ones;

```
class Car < Mod::Car; end
class Ferrari < Mod::Ferrari; end
```

and this all works perfectly... except for the single table inheritance which is now going;

```
Ferrari.all
==> select * from cars where type = "Ferrari"
Car.all
==> select * from cars where type = "Car"
```

Which is coming back empty because "Car" is an abstract concept that we never create an instance of. It's not identifying "Car" as the root model for all the others any more! Why does this functionality change when I inherit?

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the fact that rails is inferring things from the class structure and so on. What properties are available to me to reset the original behaviour after de-namespacing?

Comment: Why can't you simply move the classes out of the module ?

Comment: They're in engines, we want to keep them namespaced so we can tell which engine each class is in when we're in the app itself.